# flask app served by nginx uwsgi returns 502

Tags: nginx, uwsgi, flask

I cannot connect to a flask app (searx search engine) served by nginx and uwsgi.

My web server shows "502 Bad Gateway nginx"

Here is my nginx error: error log: /var/log/nginx/error.log

```
[crit] 2688#2688: *4 connect() to unix:/run/uwsgi/app/searx/socket.sock failed 
(2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream,
client: 216.186.XXX.XXX, server searx.mysite.com, 
request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/run/uwsgi/app/searx/socket.sock:", 
host: "searx.mysite.com"
```

So I can see that the socket.sock are not the same as the upstream.

here is my nginx.conf

```
user http;
worker_processes auto;
worker_cpu_affinity auto;

events {
    multi_accept on;
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    charset utf-8;
    sendfile on;
    tcp-nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    server_tokens off;
    log_not_found off;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;
    client_max_body_size 16M;

    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    keepalive_timeout 65;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

here is my searx.conf, the only place where I have specified where the .sock file is located:

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/searx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name searx.mysite.com;
    
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/app/searx/socket.sock;
    }
    
    root /usr/local/searx/searx-src/searx;
    location /static { }
}
```

When I look in my socket folder there is no file there...

```
ls -alh /run/uwsgi/app/searx/
```

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 searx searx 40 Jul 22 05:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root  root  60 Jul 22 05:02 ..
```

The command I am using to run uwsgi is:

```
exec chpst -u http env LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/uwsgi --master --die-on-term --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
```

the command I am using to run nginx:

```
exec chpst -u root /usr/bin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -g "daemon off;"
```

here is my searx uwsgi file

/etc/uwsgi/sites/searx.ini

```
[uwsgi]
project = searx
uid = searx
gid = searx
base = /usr/local/searx/searx-src

chdir = %(base)/%(project)
env = SEARX_SETTINGS_PATH=/etc/searx/settings.yml

disable-logging = false
workers = 2

chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true

single-interpreter = true
master = true
plugin = python
lazy-apps = true
enable-threads = true

module = searx.webapp

route-run = fixpathinfo:

virtualenv = /usr/local/searx/searx-pyenv
pythonpath = %(base)

# NOTE: if I add or delete the next line there is no difference in output
socket = /run/uwsgi/app/searx/socket.sock
```

more digging: in the searx.ini I set `disable-logging = false` and found this in the `/var/log/uwsgi/current` log:

```
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock
bind(): Permission denied [core/socket.c line 230]
Wed July 22 15:05:31 2020 - [emperor] curse the uwsgi instance searx.ini (pid: 3320)
Wed July 22 15:05:31 2020 - [emperor] removed uwsgi instance searx.ini
```

So there is definitely a problem with my searx.ini or how I am calling it?

I am not sure what other information you might need, but am happy to update the question as needed.  I have been at this for days, so I would really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Where are you specifying the socket that your `uwsgi` opens?

Comment: Please post the uwsgi ini file for the application in question.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I updated the original post with the searx uwsgi

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I do not know where `uwsgi://unix:/run/uwsgi/app/serax/socket.sock` is being set for sure.  I have tried my searx.ini file with and without the `socket = /run/uwsgi/app/serax/socket.sock` line, it does not affect the 502 error or the logging error.

Comment: Is it `serax` or `searx`? Better check everything carefully for typos.

Comment: @MichaelHampton yep, it is searx.  I am hand typing all of this so my typing dyslexia is showing.  fixed in OP and Answer.  Thank you for the careful review!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue.  Answer for google posterity...

Of course it was file permissions:

1. I added user searx to group http:  `usermod -a -G http searx`
2. I changed the searx directory to have http as it's group: `chgrp -R http /usr/local/searx`
3. I made the searx directory writable by group:  `chmod -R g+w user/local/searx`
4. Did the same with my socket.sock folder:  `chgrp -R http /run/uwsgi/app/searx`
5. and made that folder writable by group: `chmod -R g+w /run/uwsgi/app/searx`
6. Restart nginx and uwsgi.